# Angular 6 and Spring Boot how to upload folder with same folder structure on sever

Tags: spring-boot, angular6

I have to upload the whole folder on the server from Angular 6 Application

I tried the following ways to upload.

HTML

```
 <input id="selectConnector" type="file" #selectConnector class="fileLoader" (change)="filesPicked(selectConnector.files)"
      webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

Angular6

```
  filesPicked(files: File) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, file => {
      this.uploadPaths.push(file.webkitRelativePath);
      console.log("file-----" + file.webkitRelativePath);
    });
  }
  upload() {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    const files: Array<File> = this.uploadPaths;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("uploadingFiles", files[i], files[i]['name']);
    }
    this.client.post('http://localhost:8091/uploadfiles', formData)
      .subscribe(files => console.log('files', files))
  }
```

And In server side ( Spring boot Application)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadingPost(@RequestParam("uploadingFiles") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles) throws IOException {
        for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
            File file = new File(uploadingdir + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
            uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

Now all files upload successfully on the server.

**But I have to follow the same folder structure how do I do that.**

Please help.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: @SteeleDev yes, I have done it successfully

Comment: Can you please share high level how ?

Comment: @SteeleDev which one angular or spring-boot?